# How to make the Stand Alone Archiva distribution the ROOT application under Jetty?

Tags: xml, jetty, archiva

I am using the stand alone version of Archiva, it uses Jetty for its application container. It defaults to something like `http://mycompany.com:8080/archiva` I want to get rid of the application context and just make it `http://mycompany.com:8080/` so I can map it to a sub-domain using Virtual Hosts in Apache 2.2.x.

I can't figure out what to change in the configuration files. Here is the `jetty.xml` file with all the comments cut out for brevity.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- Server Thread Pool                                          -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="ThreadPool">
      <!-- Default bounded blocking threadpool 
      -->
      <New class="org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool">
        <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
        <Set name="maxThreads">250</Set>
        <Set name="lowThreads">25</Set>
      </New>
    </Set>


    <Call name="addConnector">
      <Arg>
          <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host"><SystemProperty name="jetty.host"/></Set>
            <Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="8081"/></Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">5000</Set>
        <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
          </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Set name="handler">
      <New id="Handlers" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <Set name="handlers">
         <Array type="org.mortbay.jetty.Handler">
           <Item>
             <New id="Contexts" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
           </Item>
           <Item>
             <New id="RequestLog" class="org.mortbay.jetty.handler.RequestLogHandler"/>
           </Item>
         </Array>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Set>

    <Call name="addLifeCycle">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.ContextDeployer">
          <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
          <Set name="configurationDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/contexts</Set>
          <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Call name="addLifeCycle">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.mortbay.jetty.deployer.WebAppDeployer">
          <Set name="contexts"><Ref id="Contexts"/></Set>
          <Set name="webAppDir"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/apps</Set>
      <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">false</Set>
      <Set name="extract">true</Set>
      <Set name="allowDuplicates">false</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

    <Ref id="RequestLog">
      <Set name="requestLog">
        <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.mortbay.jetty.NCSARequestLog">
          <Set name="filename"><SystemProperty name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</Set>
          <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyy_MM_dd</Set>
          <Set name="retainDays">90</Set>
          <Set name="append">true</Set>
          <Set name="extended">true</Set>
          <Set name="logCookies">false</Set>
          <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
        </New>
      </Set>
    </Ref>

    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <!-- extra options                                               -->
    <!-- =========================================================== -->
    <Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
    <Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
    <Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>

  <Array id="plusConfig" type="java.lang.String">
    <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.plus.webapp.Configuration</Item>
    <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration</Item>
    <Item>org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration</Item>
  </Array>

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Deploy all webapps in webapps-plus                          -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <Call class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext" name="addWebApplications">
    <Arg><Ref id="Contexts"/></Arg>
    <Arg>./apps</Arg>
    <Arg>org/mortbay/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml</Arg>
    <Arg><Ref id="plusConfig"/></Arg>
    <Arg type="boolean">True</Arg>
    <Arg type="boolean">False</Arg>
  </Call>

  <!-- ARCHIVA CONFIG -->

  <New id="validation_mail" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>mail/Session</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.mortbay.naming.factories.MailSessionReference">
        <Set name="user"></Set>
        <Set name="password"></Set>
        <Set name="properties">
          <New class="java.util.Properties">
            <Put name="mail.smtp.host">localhost</Put>
          </New>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>

  <!-- Archiva database -->
  <New id="archiva" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
      <Arg>jdbc/archiva</Arg>
      <Arg>
       <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
             <Set name="driverClassName">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource</Set>
             <Set name="url">jdbc:derby:<SystemProperty name="appserver.base" default=".."/>/data/databases/archiva</Set>
             <Set name="username">sa</Set>
             <Call name="addConnectionProperty">
               <Arg>create</Arg>
               <Arg>true</Arg>
             </Call>
       </New>
      </Arg>
  </New>

  <New id="archivaShutdown" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/archivaShutdown</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
             <Set name="driverClassName">org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource</Set>
             <Set name="url">jdbc:derby:<SystemProperty name="appserver.base" default=".."/>/data/databases/archiva</Set>
             <Set name="username">sa</Set>
              <Call name="addConnectionProperty">
               <Arg>shutdown</Arg>
               <Arg>true</Arg>
             </Call>
       </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>

  <!-- Users / Security Database -->

  <New id="users" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/users</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource">
        <Set name="DatabaseName"><SystemProperty name="appserver.base" default=".."/>/data/databases/users</Set>
        <Set name="user">sa</Set>
        <Set name="createDatabase">create</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>

  <New id="usersShutdown" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
    <Arg>jdbc/usersShutdown</Arg>
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDataSource">
        <Set name="DatabaseName"><SystemProperty name="appserver.base" default=".."/>/data/databases/users</Set>
        <Set name="user">sa</Set>
        <Set name="shutdownDatabase">shutdown</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

Here is the contents of my `/apps` directory:

```
[Thu Mar 03 22:03:37] [root]@[dev] /opt/archiva/apps
# dir
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Mar  2 17:34 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4.0K Mar  2 17:39 ..
drwxr-xr-x 9 root root 4.0K Mar  2 17:34 archiva
```

Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: What is the contents of your _jetty/_ `apps/` directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, there's a few options for a solution.

1. If you rename `apps/archiva` to `apps/root` then it should do exactly what you want.
2. Otherwise, you can modify your `jetty.xml` so that it deploys each app (in your case you only have 1) explicitly (rather than the way it is now, which deploys everything in `apps/`) 
   That's a bit of a pain, so I don't recommend it.
3. Save this in `apps/archiva/WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml`:

   `<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`
   `<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">`
   `<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">`
     `<Set name="contextPath">/</Set>`
   `</Configure>`
4. You can use the context deployer http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/ContextDeployer instead of deploying the app directly - this will allow you to configure the contextPath

I think option 1 is the easiest, but option 3 is pretty easy too.
2. and 4. are both more complicated.

Comment: thanks, could not find this anywhere on the internet in this clear of a explanation.

Comment: this is likely to be the default in a future version of Archiva too - see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-1030

Answer (score 0):

Implemented for coming 1.4-M3.
With an other solution :-)
${jetty.home}/contexts/archiva.xml with content

```
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/apps/archiva</Set>

  <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
  <Set name="copyWebDir">false</Set>

</Configure>
```