# DNS mapping in Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, dns, tomcat7

I have a domain `myapp.info` and a Tomcat7 instance.

Now I want to configure Tomcat 7 so that instead of entering a URL like `http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:8080/myapp-web` I will be able to use URL like `http://web.myapp.info` (and instead of `http://AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD:8080/probe/` use `probe.myapp.info`).

In order to make it work, I need to do three things:

1. Make sure that when the user enters the `myapp.info` URL, he is directed to `AAA.BBB.CCC.DDD`.
2. Setup Tomcat7 subdomains mappings.
3. Change the port of the HTTP connector.

How can I do it?

**Update 1:** Please note that at the moment there is no connection between the domain `myapp.info` and the Tomcat instance. I have bought the domain, but it is not configured to be served by the Tomcat instance (so I need to make that connection, too).

Comment: Change startup port to 80 of tomcat.

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/dns/adding-dns-records

Comment: FYI: The Tomcat7 instance is running on DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 2):

I think you must use an [Apache Server](http://httpd.apache.org) (or equivalent like [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net), [NGINX](http://nginx.org), [f5](http://www.f5.com) etc.) for port forwarding on domain/subdomains. You can configure Apache as mentioned in:

[Apache Tomcat 7 - Proxy Support HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html)

or you can inspired from:

[Mapping a subdomain to a Servlet context using Apache 2.x and Tomcat 6.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5172448/1888799)

Answer (score 0):

Make your Tomcat's monitoring port as 80. This is the default port called when no port is provided in the url.

And make your application as the default application

[Setting default application in tomcat 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325171/setting-default-application-in-tomcat-7)

Update :: You need to map your domain to the IP address of your machine which hosts the tomcat server.

Comment: You can check with the vendor of your domain to configure your IP against your domain name

Comment: What DNS records should I modify, and how?

Comment: I dont have exact idea on that. But I think the vendor of the domain name should be able to do it for you.